# Bing Maps v8 - Infobox does not appear in the expected location when the map is zoomed out

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I'm trying to use an infobox as a tooltip. I want the infobox to appear at the pushpin the mouse hovers above.

This functionality seems to work fine when the map is sufficiently zoomed in. However when the map is zoomed out - the infobox sometimes appears off the view-port (the infobox behaves as if the map has been translated horizontally).

[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wC8hS.png)

It's my suspicion that the map is simply wrapping on itself, because it's zoomed out almost all the way. Perhaps this means there are duplicate coordinates on the map canvas, though they're not shown in the view-port.

Pushpins with coordinates that appear only once on the map canvas show the infobox in the correct location.

Can anybody shed some light on this? Any help is appreciated.

I've included a basic version of my code below.

```js
var map;
function loadMapScenario() {
    map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
        credentials: 'api key',
        maxZoom: 2,
        enableSearchLogo: false,
        disableBirdseye: true,
        showDashboard: false,
        showMapLabel: true,
        showScalebar: false,
        disablePanning: true,
        disableZooming: true,
        disableKeyboardInput: true,
        disableMouseInput: false,
        disableTouchInput: true,
        disableUserInput: false
    });

    var pushpins = Microsoft.Maps.TestDataGenerator.getPushpins(10, map.getBounds());

    var infoBox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(pushpins[0].getLocation(), { title: 'title',
    description: 'description', showCloseButton: false });

    infoBox.setMap(map);

    for (var i = 0; i < pushpins.length; i++) {
        var pushpin = pushpins[i];

        Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pushpin, "mouseover", function (e) {
            infoBox.setLocation(e.target.getLocation());
        });
    }

    map.entities.push(pushpins);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bing Maps Full Width</title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div id='myMap' style='width: 100%; height: 500px;'></div>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='js/maps.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?branch=release&callback=loadMapScenario' async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

Removing the TestDataGenerator in favour of hard coded coordinate values yields the same problem.

[See here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBEON.png)

Updated JS:

```
map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
    credentials: 'api key',
    maxZoom: 2,
    disableBirdseye: true,
    showDashboard: false,
    showMapLabel: true,
    showScalebar: false,
    disablePanning: true,
    disableZooming: true
});

var pushpins = [
    new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(-28.14, -79.08), null),
    new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(-28.14, 108.51), null),
    new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(-28.14, 95.03), null),
    new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(-28.14, -134.58), null)
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a known issue with the TestDataGenerator and "world-wrap" when zoomed out all the way. Notice that not all 10 pushpins are displayed on the map. The infobox is being displayed in the correct position, but the pushpin isn't being rendered.

Also, looking through your map options there are a few that aren't needed:

- enableSearchLogo - There is no search logo in V8.
- disableBirdseye - Birdseye is not yet available in V8. We have a new
  experience and imagery coming later this fiscal year. When birdseye
  is released we will likely expose this option. You can leave this in
  your code so you don't have to make changes later.
- disableKeyboardInput/disableMouseInput/disableTouchInput/disableUserInput not used in V8

Comment: Thanks very much for your speedy answer rbrundritt, and thanks for your advice on removing the unnecessary map options. Unfortunately my problem is not with the TestDataGenerator. I've added an edit to demonstrate the problem using hard coded coordinates, see the second screenshot.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue using the array of pushpins you provided. It works perfectly for me. I only see the issue with the TestDataGenerator which is that not all the pushpins are being rendered so the infobox looks like it is in the wrong place initially.

Comment: I've been working with Chrome. Your last comment inspired me to try this in a different browser, and indeed it works perfectly with Internet Explorer! Then I asked my colleague to try it out, his results were the opposite (works in Chrome, broken in IE). Needless to say, I'm stumped.

Comment: This is likely due to the known world wrap issue that effects all parts of the map when adding data to the map when zoomed out really high.

Comment: I see, that does sound likely. Thanks again for your help. Do we have any indication as to when (or if) the Bing Maps team will address this issue?

Comment: Not at the moment. I'm hoping this will be fixed over the summer and in production by sometime in September.

Comment: rbrundritt - has the Bing Maps team had time yet to reach this issue? It seems to still be occurring. Could you suggest any suitable workarounds?

Comment: Fixing this root cause of this issue is a major undertaking that has been put on hold for now as it will require a few months worth of dev work as fixing is requires change a large portion of the underlying architecture. There is no timeline for when this will be corrected.

Comment: @matt-ankerson, In V8 I am also having the same issue, Is your issue solved? If yes please advise me the solution